# How do I associate an existing Code Review to a changeset?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-code-review

Given a set of changes that has been checked in to TFS that were code reviewed before check in, how can I move the association of the code review from the shelveset back to the resulting changeset?

We have a code review process that requires us to ask for a code review before each check in to TFS. When the code review is done, I usually queue a build with the shelveset from the code review directly into TFS (instead of unshelving the code and checking it in manually). This allows me to keep focused on my work while checking in unrelated changes, and also allows me to check in code from my colleagues in their name, again without interrupting my work.

When checking in shelvesets like this, the shelveset is automatically deleted by TFS, and then the comments from the code review cannot be seen anymore since Visual Studio cannot find the associated shelveset, like this:

[image]

Sometimes it's interesting to look back at a changeset and analyze it's code review to look for more information etc. I know the comments stored in the review are persisted in the TFS database and one is able to retrieve them by querying the DB directly (it's just Visual Studio that hides them because it cannot highlight the associated files due to the missing shelveset), but this is not feasible of course. Since I check in the exact shelveset, what I'd like to do is change the association on the code review from the shelve to the actual changeset.

The Code Review work item seems to be completely readonly (for good reason), so I can't directly change the association on the web portal or in VS, since the fields are greyed out:

[image]

What is the best approach to enable me to check in the shelvesets, delete them, and still be able to access the comments and associated lines in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

I’m a little confused about your purpose. Did you mean you want to **associate a code review to a changeset which trigger by check in the reviewed code**?

For now, **it's impossible**. The code review is linked to the changeset, but the changeset will not be linked to the code review. In other words, **it is not a two way association.**
You can conduct a code review on a checked-in changeset by going to the history right-clicking on the changeset.[image]

**However you can't view that changeset later, and see that there was indeed a code review.**

By the way, there also has been a featured request in *User Voice*. You can vote up and monitor it.

> Allow the ability to prove that a code review was done for a task
>   https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/6104804-allow-the-ability-to-prove-that-a-code-review-was

Comment: If you want to access the old comments of reviewed code and associated lines in Visual Studio, you can don't delete the shelvesets and keep them.

Comment: Hmm so even with the request review over a changeset, I won't be able to see the code review when viewing the changeset details, that is not untiutive at all. Anyways, about your comment: but then I can't use the checkin shelveset feature on the build definition, and this is a big bummer for me. Also, won't the massive amount of shelvesets clutter the TFS database down the line? I also don't want all those shelvesets on my name when searching for a specific manually created one.